# Is it possible to post 360 Photos to Facebook from an iOS App?

Tags: ios, facebook, 360-degrees

I am looking for a way to post 360 photos on Facebook through my iOS app.

I have been searching on google and couldn't find any useful answer.

Could anyone please clarify about the possibility?

Comment: Asking for external resources is off-topic. I have removed the bits where you requested external links and tutorials

Comment: if it was off-topic, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally I found [this thread](https://www.facebook.com/notes/eric-cheng/editing-360-photos-injecting-metadata/10156930564975277).

It seems Facebook reads metadata to recognize 360 degree photos.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a framework that does exactly this.

Given that you've got the permission successfully, here's what you would do:

```
[[Facebook360Manager sharedInstance] shareImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cylindrical360.jpg"]
                                      userCaption:@"Example caption..."
                                    horizontalFOV:360.0
                                  sharePreference:FacebookShareManagerPreferenceCylindricalImage
                                  completionBlock:^(NSError * _Nullable error, NSString * _Nullable postID) {
                                    if (error) {
                                      NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
                                    }else{
                                      NSLog(@"Shared successfully. Post ID: %@",postID);
                                    }
                                  }];
```

Here's a link to the framework: https://github.com/AppCoders-io/Facebook360